# Generate class from XSD - compact solution

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have XSD file, which seems rather complex (I am very new to working with XSD).

My task is to create a program, which would generate XML files based on the XSD schema (in a more detail - we will get a CSV file with the data and these need to be serialized into a XML). I did a research and tried various techniques of generating C# class from the XSD file, where the most 'compact' was **xsd2code** plugin for Visual Studio.

Nonetheless, this plugin has generated over 7,000 lines of code which quite shocked me as it was just one giant mess (for me).

My question now is - is there a better way (or maybe some switch I forgot to check) which will generate rather compact C# class? If not, then what is the next step that people have to do once they get C# class? Do they have to additional manual post processing so that the file is more 'programmer-friendly', or ...?

Thank you for your guidance; any help or tip will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you have a closer look at the x2dCode generated code? Even though it is one file with 7000 lines, there should be many classes in it. If my memory is correct, x2dcode can generate a separate file for each class as well.

Comment: Just like Kosala, I would also say that building serializable classes for an XML schema requires lots and lots of code, even for very simple XSDs. So 7000 lines doesn't actually sound like a lot, depending on the complexity of the XSD file. I don't know xsd2code, but I think in exchange for that complexity, your own code, where you use the xsd2code-generated classes, will be very high-level, comprehensive and clean.

Comment: Yes you are right, xsd2code has generated many classes, with redundant spaces (formatting), so in a reality it is half that amount. The thing was that when I was generating XML files from a class, my classes never exceeded 1k lines (I tried to keep them compact) therefore I was quite shocked when I saw those 7k lines